# Craete a Date Obj from a specific (non-standard) format

Tags: javascript

I have a date in this format "Thu Jun 01 00:00:00 CEST 2023".
How can I instantiate a Date Obj?

Comment: Any number of 'parse this random custom date string to js date' duplicates. Do some research, show what you've tried and what isn't working. SO isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom function to parse this date string as given below:

```js
function parseCustomDate(dateString){
   

  // Split the date string into individual components
  var parts = dateString.split(" ");

  // Map the month name to its corresponding index (0-based)
  var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
  ];
  var monthIndex = monthNames.indexOf(parts[1]);

  // Extract the day, month, year, and time components
  var day = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
  var year = parseInt(parts[5], 10);
  var timeParts = parts[3].split(":");
  var hour = parseInt(timeParts[0], 10);
  var minute = parseInt(timeParts[1], 10);
  var second = parseInt(timeParts[2], 10);

  // Create a new Date object using the extracted components
  var dateObj = new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hour, minute, second);

  return dateObj;

}

var dateObj = parseCustomDate("Thu Jun 01 00:00:00 CEST 2023");
alert(dateObj);
```

Comment: You've ignored the timezone

Comment: I created a standard method

Comment: Yes, which ignores the timezone